How to check if two homogeneous systems of linear equations are equivalent?
How can I check if two homogeneous systems of linear equations are equivalent in Mathematica?
Given two systems of equations:
System 1:
\begin{cases}
2x - 3y + 4z = 0 \\
-5x + 6y - 7z = 0
\end{cases}
System 2:
\begin{cases}
-3y + 2x + 4z = 0 \\
5x - 6y + 7z = 0
\end{cases}
What I mean by equivalent is that each equation in one system also exists in the same form or an equivalent or linear-combination form in the other system. In this case, the two systems are equivalent according to my definition above.
How can I check if these systems are equivalent in Mathematica?
Another example of two equivalent systems:
System 3:
\begin{cases}
x + 2y - z = 0 \\
2x + 4y - 2z = 0
\end{cases}
System 4:
\begin{cases}
x + 2y - z = 0 \\
3x + 6y - 3z = 0
\end{cases}
(* Define the equations for System 1 *)
eq1 = 2 x - 3 y + 4 z == 0;
eq2 = -5 x + 6 y - 7 z == 0;

(* Define the equations for System 2 *)
eq3 = -3 y + 2 x + 4 z == 0;
eq4 = 5 x - 6 y + 7 z == 0;


I’d use RowReduce to see if they have the same echelon form.

(*System 1*)
eq1 = 2  x - 3  y + 4  z == 0;
eq2 = -5  x + 6  y - 7  z == 0;
(*System 2*)
eq3 = -3  y + 2  x + 4  z == 0;
eq4 = 5  x - 6  y + 7  z == 0;

(*System 3*)
eq5 = 2  x + 2  y - z == 0;
eq6 = 2  x + 4  y - 2  z == 0;
(*System 4*)
eq7 = 2  y + x - z == 0;
eq8 = 3  x + 6  y - 3  z == 0;


Using CoefficientArrays and RowReduce:
f = RowReduce[Normal[CoefficientArrays[#1, #2]][[2]]] &;

f[{eq1, eq2}, {x, y, z}] === f[{eq3, eq4}, {x, y, z}]

f[{eq5, eq6}, {x, y, z}] === f[{eq7, eq8}, {x, y, z}]


True


False


This is mechanized by quantifiers.
eq1 = 2   x - 3   y + 4   z == 0;eq2 = -5   x + 6   y - 7   z == 0;
eq3 = -3   y + 2   x + 4   z == 0;eq4 = 5   x - 6   y + 7   z == 0;
Resolve[ForAll[{x, y, z}, Equivalent[eq1 && eq2, eq3 && eq4]]]


True


eq5 = 2   x + 2   y - z == 0; eq6 = 2   x + 4   y - 2   z == 0; (*System 4*) eq7 = 2   y + x - z == 0; eq8 = 3   x + 6   y - 3   z == 0;Resolve[ForAll[{x, y, z}, Equivalent[eq5 && eq6, eq7 && eq8]]] results in False.

You may solve the equations using Reduce and compare the results. E.g. System 1 and 2:
eq1 = 2 x - 3 y + 4 z == 0;
eq2 = -5 x + 6 y - 7 z == 0;

eq3 = -3 y + 2 x + 4 z == 0;
eq4 = 5 x - 6 y + 7 z == 0;

Reduce[{eq1, eq2}, {x, y, z}]
Reduce[{eq3, eq4}, {x, y, z}]

y == 2 x && z == x
y == 2 x && z == x

Therefore system 1 and 2 are equavalent.
Now system 3 and 4:
eq5 = 2 x + 2 y - z == 0;
eq6 = 2 x + 4 y - 2 z == 0;

eq7 = 2 y + x - z == 0;
eq8 = 3 x + 6 y - 3 z == 0;

x == 0 && z == 2 y
z == x + 2 y

These are not equivalent. This is easy to see if we rewrite these equations as:
eq50 = 2 x + 2 y - z == 0;
eq60 = x + 2 y - z == 0;

eq70 = x + 2 y - z == 0;
eq80 = x + 2 y - z == 0

